# is there any way to remove "action" attribute from "Form" tag and still able to send the form?

Tags: html, forms, tags, action

How to remove the action attribute in the form tag. I want to find a way to submit the form to the existing "process_login.php.php" without the action attribute. Please don't use any JavaScript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Login Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login Form</h1>
<hr>
<form action="http://corneyx.com/process_login.php" method="post">
  <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
      <td>Username:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="username" required></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="password" required></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<hr>
<!-- put your buttons here -->
<input type="hidden" name="matricnum" value="???????">
<input type="submit" name="login_form" value="Login">
<input type="reset">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't. Why don't you want to use javascript, and why do you want to remove the action tag ?

Answer (score 2):

***???***

I understand that some would like to remove the action attribute from the `<form>` tag.

However, not allowing JavaScript??

Sorry, there is just *no way*. It is just not designed that way.

Here is a [W3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) link regarding `<form>` tag if you're interested looking into vanilla HTML `<form>` and what you can do with them.

Unless you create your own browser which allows that, but let's be honest, that would defeat the purpose anyways.

Comment: This is actually a test question. It is not I want to do that. and they insist that there is a way

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to leave the action attribute blank and use ajax, but if you don't want to use JavaScript you're stuck

Comment: This is actually a test question.

Comment: Hmm if you do find a solution let me know but as to my knowledge it shouldn't be possible you could use `onSubmit="function()"` but that requires js. You may have misread the question